# Nested objects and aggregations

Tags: elasticsearch, nested

I have this mapping into my ES database which makes uses of nested objects.

Each document is a Company, and has a list of employees saved as nested objects.
Here's the mapping:

```
 "company": {
    "properties": {
        "company_name": {
           "type": "string"
        },

       "employee": {
          "properties": {
              "name": {
                 "type": "string"
               },
              "city": {
                 "type": "string"
              }
          },
          "type": "nested"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have these two companies:

```
Company A 
    [
    Smith, Dallas
    Mark, New York
    Smith, Houston
    ]

Company B 
    [
    Smith, Dallas
    Peter, New York
    Mary, Houston
    ]
```

That is, the same name can be found in different companies and more than once in each company.

The query that I need to run is supposed to be this one:

**Aggregate on city for all employees whose name is Smith**

I need to have an answer like this:

```
City for employee Smith:
   Dallas:  2
   Houston: 1
```

Remembering that employee is a list of nested objects and that I don't need any information about the company name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
{
   "size": 0,
   "aggs": {
      "my_aggs": {
         "nested": {
            "path": "employee"
         },
         "aggs": {
            "city_for_smith": {
               "filter": {
                  "term": {
                     "name": "smith"
                  }
               },
               "aggs": {
                  "result": {
                     "terms": {
                         "field": "city"
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

To also display company name for each city, you can nest another aggregation inside the last one.

```js
{
  ...
  "aggs": {
    "result": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "city"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "companyAggs": {
          "reverse_nested": {}, 
          "aggs": {
            "in_company": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "company_name"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Ryan ! It works :)
Is it possible into the same query to show also the companies name matched in the same query?

City for employee Smith:
   Dallas:  2
       Company A, B
   Houston: 1
       Company A